# Stack Exchange search API not returning results with min, max vote count

Tags: bug, search

Query to search for all question with `perl6` tag created between Oct 1 - Oct 5 2019. I'm sorting the results by `votes`.

[/2.2/search?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow)

It returns one response which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207313/why-no-each-method-on-perl6-sequences) question. It has a score of 9 at the time I write this.

Now, if I modify the above query to include a min and a max value for votes as 1 and 100 respectively, it no longer returns any results.

[/2.2/search?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&min=1&max=100&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&min=1&max=100&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow)

Is it not working as expected or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

It seems `max` is not working. When providing `min` alone, it is returning result.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems the questions API is also behaving in a similar fashion (min, max together not returning result while using min alone works)

[/2.2/questions?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&min=8&max=100&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1569888000&todate=1570233600&order=desc&min=8&max=100&sort=votes&tagged=perl6&site=stackoverflow)

**UPDATE on Oct 9, 2019:**

The `search` API is now working fine (something was fixed on StackExchange??)

The `questions` API still doesn't work when provided *max votes*.

Comment: For me, the /search call works, but the /questions call does not.

Comment: @Glorfindel Weird. The above search call (with min and max) is not returning any results for me